# A help window with/without vertical scrollbar

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to implement a help function in a web application. By pressing F1, a pop-up window shall be displayed with, or not, a vertical scrollbar.

```
$(document).keydown(function(event){

    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

    if(keycode == '112'){    //F1
        popup("help.php");    
    }

});
```

The popup function should open a new window in the middle of the screen.

```
function popup(page)
{
height = '220';
width = '440';
var str = "height=" + height + ",innerHeight=" + height;
str += ",width=" + width + ",innerWidth=" + width;
if (window.screen) {
    var ah = screen.availHeight - 30;
    var aw = screen.availWidth - 10;
    var xc = (aw - width) / 2;
    var yc = (ah - height) / 2;
    str += ",left=" + xc + ",screenX=" + xc;
    str += ",top=" + yc + ",screenY=" + yc;
};
str += ",scrollbars=1"; 
window.open(page,"name",str);
}
```

The popup window is correctly displayed but there is NO scrollbar !
The help.php is like this:

```
<?php
// for the time beeing, feed with html code. Later this script will open a
// contextual help by using header("location: help_fx.php")
?>
<div>
1<br>
2<br>
3<br>
4<br>
5<br>
6<br>
7<br>
8<br>
9<br>
10<br>
11<br>
12<br>
13<br>
14<br> 
</div>
```

Any ideas ? Thank you.

Comment: in which browser are you trying this?, your code works perfect with firefox and chrome.

Comment: with FF ! no scrollbar for me !!

Comment: I am using firefox v. 23.0 and the line of code that makes the scrollbar appears or desappear is:
str += ",scrollbars=1"; //scrollbar
str += ",scrollbars=0"; //without scrollbar

Comment: Me too ! whatever the value of scrollbars, no scrollbar for me !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried applying the CSS rule

```
<style>.myDiv{ overflow:scroll}</style> <div class="myDiv"> some content </div>
```

?  That would provide scroll bars when the content exceeds the specified container size and omit them when the content fits.

Comment: like this, before <div> ?: <style type="text/css">
overflow:scroll
</style>

Comment: It needs to be assigned to a selector. I'll edit above example.

Comment: I discovered a caveat with this today - if your container is displayed and content is added afterwards that exceeds the size, with IE8 (naturally) the scroll bar will not display until you cause the window redraw to fire (usually by resizing the window).